# Can you do a "new game+" in Muramasa: The Demon Blade?

Tags: muramasa-the-demon-blade

Started playing Muramasa recently and was wondering if once I've beaten the story I will be able to start the game as the girl or guy again and keep my level and weapons. In other words can I beat the game multiple times with the guy and girl and retain my XP and weapons?

I'm playing on Wii

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly. When you beat the game you'll be able to replay with a new character starting over from level one. *however*, you will now already have all of the swords that you forged in your first game. This is how you get the ability to forge the swords that require prerequisite swords from first characters. So, you won't start over with all of your previous abilities and life and equipment, but you will have a much nicer selection of swords (though you won't be able to use them for a while).

Additionally, there is an even harder difficulty setting that is unlocked. I forget the exact name, but it is *exceedingly* difficult. The game-play is basically that of Shura (hard) except that you *never* level up and you have a single hit point. What this means is that if you get hit, even once, you die. It's certainly a very compelling challenge, but probably not what you're looking for (I could barely even beat the first boss).

Comment: Shiranui is the name of the harder difficulty. It's very amusing.